# error rc2104 undefined keyword or key name MS in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

There is a vs2008 mfc project, now I use vs2013 to build it, there is a error,
"error rc2104 undefined keyword or key name MS"

How should I fix this error?

IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 244, 170
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
FONT 8, "**MS Shell Dlg**", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
END

Comment: When I open the RC file, vs2013 cn prompts that some characters will be repalced, after that, run into compile error.

Answer (score 0):

open your \MCL\MFC\Include\AfxRes.h and add this include directive:

```
#include <winresrc.h>
```

Information can be found in [Resource Compiler Error RC2104](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2z28y0f.aspx)

Comment: The document you [linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2z28y0f.aspx) to explains: *"If you encounter this message: `undefined keyword or key name: MFT_STRING` open \MCL\MFC\Include\AfxRes.h and add this include directive: `#include <winresrc.h>`"*. That solution doesn't address the error message the OP posted.